# Is there a way to find a list of associated words to a named entity?

Tags: natural-language-processing, named-entity-recognition

Is there a way to find a list of associated words to a named entity?

For instance, let the named entity be FIFA. Now FIFA is a Football Organization and hence related to the term football and all the terms related to football like jersey, footballers, goal, goalkeeper, halftime, penalty, freekick et cetera.

Is there a way we could do that? I have tried Babelnet but didn't get the desired results or anything even close to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to find a list of associated words to a Named Entity. This can be done by using word embeddings, specifically word2vec or GloVe, which are models that can capture the semantic relationship between words. By finding the cosine similarity between the Named Entity and other words in the vector space, you can identify the words that are semantically close to the Named Entity. Another option is to use a knowledge graph, such as DBpedia or Wikipedia, to extract information about the Named Entity, including related concepts and categories. This approach can help you identify a more comprehensive set of associated words, but it requires more processing and computational resources.